# Accessing arguments collection in bind function

Tags: javascript

When returning `.bind()` from a higher order function, is it possible to access the `arguments` collection within the bound context?

Take the following function as an example:

```
function reverse(fn) {
     return function ()  { 
        return fn.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments).reverse()) 
     };
}
```

Ideally I'd like to remove the inner function wrapper and simply return something like:

`return fn.apply.bind(fn, [].slice.call(arguments).reverse());`

(Obviously `arguments` is scoped to the outer function and not the returned function, which is what I'm after).

Is this possible through some mechanism I'm unaware of or is the function wrapper a necessity?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're _actually_ trying to achieve...

Comment: You can make a partial function of it and return that

Comment: The removal of the inner function (`return function () {...}`)

Comment: sure, but what is the _outer_ function supposed to do?

Comment: The outer function takes a function, and returns a function that is the same as the one passed in, except the arguments are reversed. So `reverse(console.log)("World", "Hello") -> "Hello" "World"`

Comment: OK, that's what I suspected, although I wasn't sure...  bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind` is a good way of setting the context and/or a *fixed* initial parameter list when you cannot control the lexical scope of the function you're trying to `.bind`.

Internally `.bind` just creates a function anyway, so offers no advantage here - in my experience it has few other uses that an inner function wouldn't achieve better.

In fact in this case it simply can't work - you have to provide some sort of scope for where the `.reverse()` call happens, and the only place that can be is in that inner function.

Comment: This is just for practice but it would have been more aesthetically pleasing to my pedantic mind if I could have removed the inner function got away with a one liner. Ah well. Onward and up. Cheers for answering Alnitak.

Comment: If it's just for the aesthetics of a one liner, you could do this:
`return Function(["fn"], "fn.apply(fn, [].slice.call(arguments, 1).reverse());").bind(null, fn)`; but that's just awful for my taste.

Comment: @JamieDixon ultimately, you _have_ to arrange for the argument array to be reversed before invoking the desired function, and AFAIK that's simply impossible with a call to `.bind`.  You have to provide some scope in which that reversal takes place, and your inner function provides that.